# Automatically whitelist emails to Google Schema Markup

Tags: email, gmail, schema, google-schemas

I am interested in providing my users with custom emails account, and would like to whitelist every one of them in Google Schema Markup.

As for now, I have found the next form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfT5F1VJXtBjGw2mLxY2aX557ctPTsCrJpURiKJjYeVrugHBQ/viewform?pli=1

Using this form, you can manually submit a request to add your email address (after doing all the preparations and steps Google asks for) to the Google Schema Markup whitelist.

My question is, since I am interested in opening email accounts automatically for my users and would like to also whitelist them automatically to Google Schema Markup, if there's a way to do so, or do I have to / have my users to complete all the steps and submit the form every time manually?

The form I linked has the next question:

> From what email address are these emails sent?

Maybe there's an option to use a wildcard or to whitelist the whole domain the emails will be based on? (I am planning to use a single domain for all the email accounts)

The emails my users will send are using the same pattern and will have a very similar content (mostly receipts and invoices).

Comment: Checked the [Overview for Google Schema](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview) and found no guide with regard to what you're trying to do. File a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry). The closest thing I found on whitelisting with regard to Gmail is [this doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60751?hl=en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I see that there is indeed no way of submitting a whole IP / emails in bulk to Google Schema Markup.

I have filed a feature request as @noogui suggested. Hopefully they'll do something about it in the future.